# How can I configure two monitors from two video sources?

Tags: multiple-monitors

I am currently only able to get a single display running (from Nvidia card), and I want to use a second monitor using my motherboard's video output. The system settings only display the first monitor, though during boot, the second monitor displays some graphics and information. Does anybody have any experience with this?

Comment: Usually when you install a PCIe graphics card it will disable the onboard graphics. Does the nVidia card have more than 1 connector? Most cards these days have the ability to do dual display.

Comment: What happens when you open NVIDIA's config tool, do you see both monitors detected?